# How do I assign values to my nodes instantiates in my OPC UA server (C # code)

Tags: c#, server, opc-ua

I am a beginner in OPC UA server and using C # to develop the server. I have used UA Modeller to create my objects and include it in the server while using C #.

I have instantiated the objects into my server and now I want to assign values to these nodes ? How do I do that? and how can I make these assigned values constantly change as if it is attached to a real time data source ?

```
        Console.WriteLine("Loading the MyIM Model.");
            ImportUaNodeset(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), "myinformationmodel_1.1.0.xml");

            Console.WriteLine("myIM sucessfully loaded");

            CreateObjectSettings settings = new CreateObjectSettings()
            {
                ParentNodeId = UnifiedAutomation.UaBase.ObjectIds.ObjectsFolder,
                ReferenceTypeId = UnifiedAutomation.UaBase.ReferenceTypeIds.Organizes,
                RequestedNodeId = new NodeId("myIM", DefaultNamespaceIndex),
                BrowseName = new QualifiedName("Controllers", DefaultNamespaceIndex),
                TypeDefinitionId = UnifiedAutomation.UaBase.ObjectTypeIds.FolderType
            };
            ObjectNode controllersNode = CreateObject(Server.DefaultRequestContext, settings);

            settings = new CreateObjectSettings()
            {
                ParentNodeId = controllersNode.NodeId,
                ReferenceTypeId = UnifiedAutomation.UaBase.ReferenceTypeIds.Organizes,
                RequestedNodeId = new NodeId("Bodyshop", DefaultNamespaceIndex),
                BrowseName = new QualifiedName("Bodyshop", DefaultNamespaceIndex),
                TypeDefinitionId = new NodeId(myAG.myIM.ObjectTypes.BodyshopProductionEquipmentType, DefaultNamespaceIndex)

            };
            CreateObject(Server.DefaultRequestContext, settings);

            settings = new CreateObjectSettings()
            {
                ParentNodeId = controllersNode.NodeId,
                ReferenceTypeId = UnifiedAutomation.UaBase.ReferenceTypeIds.Organizes,
                RequestedNodeId = new NodeId("PaintShop", DefaultNamespaceIndex),
                BrowseName = new QualifiedName("PaintShop", DefaultNamespaceIndex),
                TypeDefinitionId = new NodeId(myAG.myIM.ObjectTypes.PaintshopProductionEquipmentType, DefaultNamespaceIndex)

            };
            CreateObject(Server.DefaultRequestContext, settings);
            
            settings = new CreateObjectSettings()
            {
                ParentNodeId = controllersNode.NodeId,
                ReferenceTypeId = UnifiedAutomation.UaBase.ReferenceTypeIds.Organizes,
                RequestedNodeId = new NodeId("ProductionMainFolder", DefaultNamespaceIndex),
                BrowseName = new QualifiedName("ProductionMainFolder", DefaultNamespaceIndex),
                TypeDefinitionId = new NodeId(myAG.myIM.ObjectTypes.ProductionEquipmentType, DefaultNamespaceIndex)

            };
            CreateObject(Server.DefaultRequestContext, settings);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which OPC UA C# library you are using but I can explain it in general

The `CreateObject` method usually return a state object. In case of [OPC Foundation C# library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OPCFoundation.NetStandard.Opc.Ua/) the state object is of type **BaseDataVariableState** and has the property called `Value` of type object. Which you could set at anytime.

While updating the value you should also update the `Timestamp` property (best set to *DateTime.UtcNow*) and clear the change mask (call method `ClearChangeMasks`).

To simulate a data source, you typically start a timer (e.g. after the end of `CreateAddressSpace` method), and everytime the timer is elapsed you update value and timestamp of your variables instances.
The OPC foundation library provides a class called `Opc.Ua.Test.DataGenerator` that generates random values for you and is aware of the OPC UA base types.

Some inspiration if you need something different then random values, like dips, spikes, trends you can have a look into the [plugins folder of iot-edge-opc-plc](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iot-edge-opc-plc/tree/master/src/PluginNodes) which is an OPC UA server simulation.

If you are looking for a way to to use your own OPC UA classes as C# classes you could start with the [DataTypes example](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard-Samples/blob/master/Workshop/DataTypes/README.md) from OPC Foundation.